# Use Views to display tabs such as, "Add User Relationship," "Send message," etc

Tags: 7, views, routes

In D7, is there a module that allows to display tabs similar to the following ones, in Views?

- Add Relationship
- edit
- Messages
- Send Private message

I want to add these tabs as views blocks so I can place them where I want.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand your question clearly, where are you getting those tabs from? If its a View you could use the [Views Display Tabs](http://drupal.org/project/viewsdisplaytabs) module, unfortunately the D7 port still hasn't been started it seems: http://drupal.org/node/985960 - Its a good time to write a patch for it or hire someone to do it for you.